# Tkinter Entry not registering text

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm fairly new to Tkinter and I tried to make a program that automatically generates math questions and outputs if the user is right or not, I tried to get it to print out the user input but the variable always stores nothing, what am I doing wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio Code on macOS Big Sur with 3.9.12

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import Entry


login = tk.Tk()
login.title('Lmao Questions')
window_width = 600
window_height = 400
screen_width = login.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = login.winfo_screenheight()


center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)
login.resizable(False, False)

login1 = tk.Label(login, text="Random Question:")
login1.pack()

number1 = tk.Label(login,text="click button to generate number!")

number2 = tk.Label(login,text="L+Ratio")
operators = ["-", "+","/","*"]
answercorrect = 1
def callback():
    numbe = random.randint(0,3)
    num = random.randint(1,500)
    numb = random.randint(1,500)
    global answercorrect

    if numbe == (0):
        answercorrect = num - numb
    if numbe == (1):
        answercorrect = num + numb
    if numbe == (2):
        answercorrect = num / numb
    if numbe == (3):
        answercorrect = num * numb

    question= str(num) + " " + operators[numbe] + " " + str(numb)
    number1.config(text=question)
    number1.pack()
    print(answercorrect)
 

button = ttk.Button(login, text="Get Question", command=callback)
button.pack()

adsjlfesspacing = tk.Label(login,text=" ")

adsjlfesspacing.pack()



login.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')


check = tk.Tk()
check.title('Check answer')
check.geometry("300x200")

def callback1():
    print(answercorrect)
    print(AnswerUser.get())
    showinfo(title="good job", message = f"you entered {AnswerUser.get()}, the correct answer was {answercorrect}")

infolabel = tk.Label(check, text= "Check Answers:")
infolabel.pack()

AnswerUser = tk.StringVar()
Answer_entry = ttk.Entry(check, textvariable=AnswerUser)
Answer_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
Answer_entry.focus()

buton = ttk.Button(check, text="Check", command=callback1)
buton.pack()





check.mainloop() 
login.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see multiple calls to `Tk()` in this program, which causes all sorts of problems.  You need to use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `textvariable` attribute for your `Entry` - try this instead

```
def callback1():
    print(answercorrect)
    # print(AnswerUser.get())
    showinfo(
        title="good job",
        # call '.get()' on the Entry widget instead
        message = f"you entered {Answer_entry.get()}, the correct answer was {answercorrect}"
    )

...

# AnswerUser = tk.StringVar() - you don't need this
Answer_entry = ttk.Entry(check)  # and you can skip the 'textvariable'
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped so much cant believe i messed that up

Comment: I’m glad it worked out! If you’re satisfied, please accept this answer so others know this question has been answered. :)